# Calling conventions -- how to specify them in Assembly? Or are they already implcitly specified?

Tags: assembly, nasm, calling-convention

Algthouh I've been reading about calling conventions and I know what they are, I've not found any mention about which plathorms use which calling conventions or is it what a programmer has to explicitly setup by some directive to the assembly compiler. In other words, how to set them up explicitly.

Will anyone help me understand? Or are there any default calling conventions for certain plathorms and assembly compilers? Or .... how does that work in general?

Comment: I think all platforms/compilers explain the calling conventions they use. Usually the ABI is even named after a certain platform, so it's quite easy to know where they are used.

Comment: Generally speaking it is the responsibility of the author of the assembly code to follow the convention, possibly some limited assistance from advanced macro assemblers. They are also only _conventions_ in the sense that you need to follow the correct one interfacing with external libraries but you can make up you'd prefer internally within your internal code, although the interfaces may be somewhat wide on certain systems which need to inspect the call stack at run-time (certain exception unwinding and overlay systems). In any event the your system should offer a documented ABI to follow.

Comment: @doynax, are  I free any convention regardless on a plathorm I'm writting an application for?

Comment: @Jodooomi: Not exactly. The platform's ABI will provide a range of constraints which you are required to obey on top of the formal calling convention contract between libraries. The requirements are usually fairly lax however and so you typically have free reign to choose, say, pass parameters in arbitrary registers internally within your own code. On the other hand operating systems typically have fairly tight strictures on how you may treat the stack, and as I mentioned any introspection performed by the system tends to limit your freedom.

Comment: @Jodooomi: Think of the calling convention as a contract between your application and the external code with which it interacts. It is a more-or-less arbitrary convention which you can agree on but which may be modified as long as both caller and callee are in on it. Of course an operating system, if present, will always interacts with your code in some fashion and so your code will need to obey that stipulations of that particular contract to the letter.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few points that answer your question:

- Operating Systems declare a calling convention to use it's services
- Compilers generate code that accept and call functions based on directives declared as part of the function signature. Some compilers default if no directive says otherwise and some let you pass the directive on invocation of the compiler.
- Assembly code 'abides' by these various conventions based on what (or who?) they are calling.

However; in a pure assembly program, the code in assembly can call itself using just about any protocol it wants to define. For example:

```
bar: 
    add rdi, rsi
    mov rax, rdi
    ret 

foo:
    mov  rdi, arg1
    mov  rsi, arg2
    call bar
    ret
```

follows a convention where the caller `foo` passes arguments in registers RDI, RSI as the order the callee is expecting. This is a familiar convention for System V (linux, mac, etc.).

But because I am not calling any OS or libraries I am free to change the above to:

```
bar: 
    add r11, r12
    mov r13, r11
    ret 

foo:
    mov  r11, arg1
    mov  r12, arg2
    call bar
    ret
```

I could also use a stack based convention for passing arguments. One thing to be aware of when using your own convention is any considerations that the OS may impose. These are readily understood by grabbing yourself a copy of the target OS ABI document.

Comment: is there a special calling convention directive in assembly, specifically in nasm?

Comment: @Jodooomi - No, the only conventions you are constrained by are the OS system calls (or interrupts), any library you may call from your code, or the expectations of the caller. In the case of the later, consider your assembly function being called by code someone wrote in 'C'.

Answer (score 0):

Old MS-DOS MASM (x86 real mode), to use C function / calling convention:

```
printf    PROTO arg1:Ptr Byte, printlist: VARARG

;The first argument is a pointer to a string. The second is a keyword
; that permits a variable number of arguments.

          .STACK 100h
          .DATA
fmtlist   BYTE   "%s, %d, %lu", 0Ah,0
string_1  BYTE   "signed byte and unsigned double word", 0
data_1    SBYTE  -2
data_2    DWORD  0FFFFFFFFh

          .CODE
main      PROC
INVOKE    printf, ADDR fmtlist, ADDR string_1, data_1, data_2
main      ENDP
          ret
          end
```

Then MASM puts the arguments and return address (IP), also SP frame into stack in correct order (IIRC there were some differences between C and Pascal modules).

Back to 2017, here is [Overview of x64 Calling Conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235286.aspx), also [Parameter Passing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zthk2dkh.aspx) (Windows).

> The x64 Application Binary Interface (ABI) uses a four register
>   fast-call calling convention by default...There is a strict one-to-one
>   correspondence between the arguments to a function call and the
>   registers used for those arguments. Any argument that doesn’t fit in 8
>   bytes, or is not 1, 2, 4, or 8 bytes, must be passed by reference.
>   There is no attempt to spread a single argument across multiple
>   registers...

Integer values are passed in RCX, RDX, R8, and R9... floating point - XMM0 – XMM3, others passed on the stack.

Some sample Windows x64 asm [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/introduction-to-x64-assembly).

Comment: Pascal calling convention has callee restoring stack (via ret xxx), C calling convention has caller restoring stack (so function uses ret 0), and caller uses add sp,xxx.